# Matlab GUI, share data among callback functions

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

It took me a long time to do this. I can search a lot of tutorial teaching this, but I cannot do it anyway, so I need some help and have to ask question here. In GUI, there are two listboxes and two push buttons. I click pushbutton2 and we get data. Now in function pushbutton1_callback, I need to use data. I don't want to use 'Global' because it's not a good method. Thanks a lot.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% I need to get  data from function pushbutton2

function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

data = get(handles.listbox2,'String')
```

Comment: Store the data in the figure's `'UserData'` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the handles structure of the GUI to store all the data you want. Look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html) as well.

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

handles.data = get(handles.listbox2,'String') % Store the data directly in  the structure.

guidata(handles,hObject); %// update the structure. Important!

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

%// Here use the data as you wish:

DatatoUse = handles.data;
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: Hello, your answer did solve my problem, but it causes a new problem. when it comes to guidata(handles,hObject); the stuff in handles is updated, and I still have this code: newitem = handles.element. this newitem is changed, i need newitem remains same. do you know how to deal with this? thanks a lot. I am still new to GUI.Do you need more details to solve it?